# Un-overriding methods in java?

Tags: java, class, methods, subclass, overriding

I understand the concept of superclass methods being overridden if they are declared public. However, I'd like to know if there's a way to call on a superclass' method instead of the subclass' method. For example, `toString` under a superclass will print out certain data fields while the `toString` under a subclass will print out another set of data fields. I want to invoke both methods. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you are asking from an instance field you can't... Only from the child class method itself you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a superclass's toString() method from within a subclass, you would call

```
super.toString();
```

So if you wanted an object's `toString()` method to call its superclass's `toString()` method at the same time, you would do

```
String str = // whatever the toString() of this object is
return str + super.toString();
```

And presto!

Answer (score 2):

from child class's method (which is being overriden) you can call `super.toString()` to call super's version and then on next statements child versions

Answer (score 1):

you need to call toString() of the childe,
where the child will call super.toString();

Answer (score 1):

You can always call super.toString() from your subclass, to invoke the super class method. You will get call the "last" overridden version if not call with "super" explicitly, this is called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).